# upper limit Of Dependent Variable comsol

Tags: comsol

Hello I'm trying to solve a 3D problem with several PDE's attached and I need to define an upper limit for my variables, I know that in comsol it is possible to define lower limits, but I can't find any way to define the upper limits. This is important because one of the variables is reaching very high values and hindering the convergence of the model. Anyone who can help will be very grateful!

Comment: I know strictly nothing about comsol, but can't you just `-x` or 1/x` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late but you could try using min(limit,function or variable). This way if the value of your variable goes above the limit, comsol will just use the value of the limit.